# Symfony 4 Bundle: AuthenticationUtils but no such service exists

Tags: php, service, dependency-injection, bundle, symfony4

I'm trying to make a Bundle (Symfony 4) for managing users of all our projects and I'm having a problem.

> Cannot autowire argument $authenticationUtils of "App\Aroban\Bundle\UtilisateurBundle\Controller\SecurityController::login()": it references class "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils" but no such service exists.

I do not understand why the service is not injected...

In the composer.json of the project, there is "symfony/security-bundle": "4.3.*"

In the Bundle:

SecurityController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Aroban\Bundle\UtilisateurBundle\Controller;

use App\Aroban\Bundle\UtilisateurBundle\Entity\Utilisateur;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenGenerator\TokenGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Swift_Mailer;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('@Utilisateur/security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

.......
}
```

Configuration.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Aroban\Bundle\UtilisateurBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('utilisateur');
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->getRootNode();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

UtilisateurExtension.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Aroban\Bundle\UtilisateurBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class UtilisateurExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }
}
```

services.yaml (bundle)

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means

  App\Aroban\Bundle\UtilisateurBundle\:
    resource: '../../*'
    exclude: '../../{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

  App\Aroban\Bundle\UtilisateurBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../Controller/*'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

When I execute the command

> php bin/console debug:container | grep security

I do not see the service ...

> Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface                      alias for "security.csrf.token_manager"
>     Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenGenerator\TokenGeneratorInterface         alias for "security.csrf.token_generator"
>     Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\TokenStorageInterface             alias for "security.csrf.token_storage"
>     doctrine.orm.security.user.provider                                            Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider
>     maker.security_config_updater                                                  Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Security\SecurityConfigUpdater
>     security.csrf.token_generator                                                  Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenGenerator\UriSafeTokenGenerator
>     security.csrf.token_manager                                                    Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManager
>     security.csrf.token_storage                                                    Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\SessionTokenStorage
>     twig.extension.security_csrf                                                   Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\CsrfExtension
>     twig.runtime.security_csrf                                                     Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\CsrfRuntime
>    // To search for a specific service, re-run this command with a search term. (e.g. debug:container
>    // log)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to `composer install` afterwards ?

This will install the dependencies you specified in your composer.json

You may have to remove your composer.lock so that it installs your added dependency (see the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-json-project-setup) ). The simplest way may be to use composer require symfony/security-bundle:4.3 instead

Comment: You may have to remove your composer.lock so that it installs your added dependency (see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-json-project-setup )

The simplest way may be to use `composer require symfony/security-bundle:4.3` instead

Comment: You could edit your answer to put this information in the answer itself.